# Rails route not working using resource :model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, models

In my Rails 3.1 app, I have a model named "Child"

In my routes.rb file, I have the line:

```
resources :children
```

Here is the whole routes.rb text:

```
  root :to => "pages#home"

  resources :children
```

Here is the full rake routes results (note that the majority of the routes are related to ActiveAdmin):

```
                  children GET        /children(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"children"}
                           POST       /children(.:format)                       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"children"}
                 new_child GET        /children/new(.:format)                   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"children"}
                edit_child GET        /children/:id/edit(.:format)              {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"children"}
                     child GET        /children/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"children"}
                           PUT        /children/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"update", :controller=>"children"}
                           DELETE     /children/:id(.:format)                   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"children"}
```

When I run "rake routes" I see this line in the results:

```
children GET  /children(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"children"}
```

This is the code in my ChildrenController:

```
     def index
        @children = Child.all

        @base_class = "children-index"
        @title = "Your Children"

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # children/index.html.erb
            format.json { render :json => @children }
        end
    end

    def show
        @child = Child.find(params[:id])

        @base_class = "child-show"
        @title = child_name(@child)

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # children/show.html.erb
            format.json { render :json => @child }
        end
    end
```

When I visit the url "/children" I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"children"}
```

Here's the full trace:

```
Started GET "/children" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-07 13:06:24 -0600
  Processing by ChildrenController#index as HTML
  Child Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `children`.* FROM `children` 
Rendered children/index.html.erb within layouts/application (65.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 166ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"children"}):
    1: <h1><%= title %></h1>
    2: <ul>
    3:  <%= @children.each do |child| %>
    4:      <li><%= link_to child.child_name(child), child_path(@child) %></li>
    5:  <% end %>
    6: </ul>
  app/views/children/index.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_children_index_html_erb__674498165009231817_70298485459960'
  app/views/children/index.html.erb:3:in `each'
  app/views/children/index.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_children_index_html_erb__674498165009231817_70298485459960'
  app/controllers/children_controller.rb:9:in `index'

Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

Why is "/children" trying to execute the "show" action and why does the show action act like the route is not there? All of my other models have worked just fine thus far using the "resource :model" instruction.

Comment: Can you post your whole routes file? There may be something interfering

Comment: can you provide chunk of code where link_to show is?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: will only look for the show action for GET /children url if the routes have a singular mapping resource :children.

Comment: sorry, not the full trace, the output from the server. the console output from the "No route matches"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the server output we have this:
`Processing by ChildrenController#index as HTML`
that confirms the route is right.

but inside your template you are using an route that the server can't find.

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"children"}):

```
1: <h1><%= title %></h1>
2: <ul>
3:  <%= @children.each do |child| %>
4:      <li><%= link_to child.child_name(child), child_path(@child) %></li>
5:  <% end %>
6: </ul>
```

more precisely, in line 4 you got a problem, probably here: `child_path(@child)`

are you using any custom ids for your models (overriding the to_param method) ?

---

just to make it clear, this is not a route error, is a template error

Comment: Ah, I understand. I'm a bit too noob at Rails to know each place to look, but this entire question just gave me a path for future troubleshooting. I think I can figure out what to do from here.

Comment: do not worry, when you are learning is okay to make mistakes.